# C - memory allocation issue - need explanation

Tags: c, pointers, structure, c-strings

Recently, I have encountered a problem with C pointers.
As you might see, I've got a loop that reads data from STDIN. The problem is I don't quite understand what I've done.

I allocated memory for this struct_CONTAINER structure. I desired to have an array of c-strings with BUFFER_SIZE length inside it. If I understand correctly, this array contains BUFFER_SIZE (char *) objects - and that means that the weight of this array would be 8 * BUFFER_SIZE bytes (8 bytes at most for each char pointer). So, for example, if BUFFER_SIZE is defined with value 10, then that gives us 80 bytes for this array and probably the whole structure would have a similar size.

The problem is I am able to iterate over that pointer with values greater than BUFFER_SIZE and what is weird for me - that memory is not NULL. I know that in that loop I might be trying to access some other already allocated memory. But I'm not sure. If somebody would be nice and told me what I am doing right and wrong. It's possible that the memory allocation is too large. Thanks in advance!

```
char *item = NULL;

if( dup2( STDIN_FILENO, fdin ) < 0 ){
    perror( "dup2(  )" );
    exit( errno );
}

memset( reading, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE );

struct struct_CONTAINER{
    char *container[BUFFER_SIZE];
};


while( ( r_control = read( fdin, reading, BUFFER_SIZE-1 ) ) > 0 ){
    item = &shmemContainer->container[i++];
    strcpy(item, reading);
    memset( reading, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE );
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to show you what is the type of "item" variable

Comment: The type of item does not help. Consider reading the answer of @Grijesh Chauhan.

Comment: Do you allocate memory for the strings pointed to by the "container" array elsewhere?

Comment: @Digikata you are correct this can be an additional error by OP. I added you point in my answer

Comment: now im trying to allocate this memory with fully understanding. I'll tell you later:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct member `container` is of `char*` type means its array of strings. you are assigning to  `item` address of string that `char**` and try to call `strcpy(item, reading);`

You are doing wrong at-least in one of following statments.

```
 item = &shmemContainer->container[i++];
        ^   is wrong 
 strcpy(item, reading);
         ^ or this is wrong
```

**[ANSWER]**  (*as you commented first point is error in your code*)
Because [precedence of `->` operator is higher then `&`](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html). You should get a warning when you compile your code.

- if first expression `item = &shmemContainer->container[i++];`  is wrong write it like:

  `item = (&shmemContainer)->container[i++];`
- and if `strcpy(item, reading);`  is wrong correct it like:

  `strcpy(*item, reading);`

And as I can understand from your while loop you wants to read string from `fdin` into string array and you can do like:

```
while( ( r_control = read( fdin, reading, BUFFER_SIZE-1 ) ) > 0 ){
    reading[r_control] = '\0'; // null ternimate
    strcpy(shmemContainer->container[i++],reading) ;
    memset( reading, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE );
}
```

code `reading[r_control] = '\0';`  added this because first time you are missing `memset()`, remember `read()` doesn't terminate `\0` string it self.

**EDIT**:
Consider @Digikata's comment because you are doing `strcpy()` to `container[]` be sure that you allocate memory for each string.

My suggestion:

`container[]` is array of string so you can allocate memory in your while loop, like:

```
i = 0;
while( ( r_control = read( fdin, reading, BUFFER_SIZE-1 ) ) > 0 ){
    reading[r_control] = '\0'; // null ternimate
    shmemContainer->container[i] = malloc(strlen(reading) + 1);
    strcpy(shmemContainer->container[i++],reading) ;
    memset( reading, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE );
}
```

Added memory allocation if you are missing.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify type of "item" variable. It's

char *item; this is the single c-string from my array;

Im doing some other operations and I wanted to shorten it a little.
The whole code works, but im surprised that I can access array items over its length and that place in memory is not null

Comment: @Kuntaker I have already mention in my answer for this. if your `item` is `char*` type then `item = &shmemContainer->container[i++];` is wrong either add `()` or change your while loop as i have written.

Comment: Let me explain how I understand that and it would be kind of you if you correct me

1. operator "->" > "&" operator, so firstly im accessing member
of `shmemContainer` which is `container`. 
2. Then with operator "[]" im getting value that pointer points at
(im not sure here)
3. Because of that i need address of that pointer, so im getting it with & operator
4. and finally im assigning this address to (char *) pointer
 like `item = &shmemContainer->container[i++];`

Comment: i divided my answer into 2 parts. Doing this in your way:
`strcpy(shmemContainer->container[i++],reading);`
the process terminates successfuly(0 returned) immediately after putting something to stdin.the fun thing is, i cannot do that:
`strcpy(&shmemContainer->container[i++],reading);` the compiler says im trying to pass char ** and the type of argument is just char *. But as you saw before i actually did this in other way.

Why is that so? And why my solution works and yours not? Im confused

Comment: @Kuntaker That is what I written in my answer that `->` has higher precedence over `&` so first you get string from `container[]` then applies `&` to string that means `char**` hence writing `strcpy(&shmemContainer->container[i++],reading);` is wrong and correct is what i suggested you in my answer. If you still have doubt you can give me the code at [codepad](http://codepad.org/) I can comment your code

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't prevent you from indexing past the the intended memory location. For example:

```
char astring[5] = "0123";  // there is a zero at index 4 
char* ptr = astring;       // ptr[4] == 0

printf("%c", ptr[5]);  // reads a byte beyond the end of the string array
```

Your code needs to logically prevent that from occurring, as there is frequently data there, 
but writing it (and sometimes even reading it) will result in undefined behavior. So in your code, it's normal for the area beyond your container to read as not NULL.

BTW, it's not clear from your question if you understand the difference between a char* type pointing to a c-string and the allocated memory area for example the "ptr" the "astring" variable in the code above. Your sample code doesn't allocate any memory for the string.